# Excel Tax Calculator

Tags: excel

I am making a tax calculator in excel. I have used the if and command for this purpose but it shows results to the limited slabs. I am posting my formula and the tax table. Please help me in shortening the formula.

```
Tax Slabs               Tax Rate    Additional Tax
 -             400,000  0%   -   
   400,000     500,000  2.00%        -   
   500,000     750,000  5.00%        2,000 
   750,000   1,400,000  10.00%      14,500 
 1,400,000   1,500,000  12.50%      79,500 
 1,500,000   1,800,000  15.00%      92,000 
 1,800,000   2,500,000  17.50%     137,000 
 2,500,000   3,000,000  20.00%     259,500 
 3,000,000   3,500,000  22.50%     359,500 
 3,500,000   4,000,000  25.00%     472,000 
 4,000,000   7,000,000  27.50%     597,000 
 7,000,000              30.00%   1,422,000
```

Tax slabs are in column H and I . Tax Rates slabs is in column J and the Additional tax is in column K.

Here is the formula

```
=IF(AND($D8>$H$8,$D8<=$I$8),(($D8-$H$8)*$J$8+$K$8),IF(AND($D8>$H$9,$D8<=$I$9),(($D8-
$H$9)*$J$9+$K$9),IF(AND($D8>$H$10,$D8<=$I$10),(($D8-
$H$10)*$J$10+$K$10),IF(AND($D8>$H$11,$D8<=$I$11),(($D8-
$H$11)*$J$11+$K$11),IF(AND($D8>$H$12,$D8<=$I$12),(($D8-
$H$12)*$J$12+$K$12),IF(AND($D8>$H$13,$D8<=$I$13),(($D8-
$H$13)*$J$13+$K$13),IF(AND($D8>$H$14,$D8<=$I$14),(($D8-
$H$14)*$J$14+$K$14),IF(AND($D8>$H$15,$D8<=$I$15),(($D8-
$H$15)*$J$15+$K$15,IF(AND($D8>$H$16,$D8<=$I$16),(($D8-
$H$16)*$J$16+$K$16,IF(AND($D8>$H$17,$D8<=$I$17),(($D8-
$H$17)*$J$17+$K$17),IF(AND($D8>$H$18,$D8<=$I$18),(($D8-
$H$18)*$J$18+$K$18),IF(AND($D8>$H$19),(($D8*$J$19)+$K$19),0))))))))))))))
```

where D is the annual taxable salary column.

Kindly look into it and help me out.

Comment: yeah this formula is super crazy ;) i dont think you can shorten it... i would create macro with loop and getting value between tax slabs, gettin tax rate and whatever you want:) maybe it will be longer, but much clearer :) @EDIT if you still want do it in formula.. check this site https://exceljet.net/formula/count-cells-between-two-numbers you can count rows and set J column with (H/I)maxrows-counted rows to get tax rate...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace it with a set of vlookups:

```
=((D8-VLOOKUP(D8,H8:K19,1,1))*VLOOKUP(D8,H8:K19,3,1))+VLOOKUP(D8,H8:K19,4,1)
```

Comment: Thank You so much. It really works and shortens the formula to almost a single line.